# Make an SVG image's elements not scannable in devtools

Tags: svg

I made a logo from SVG, and it looks and works fine.  The only problem is that when I go into dev tools and then use the select an element tool, it also shows the elements inside of the SVG image as separate elements, rather than the SVG being A single element.  I am using an embed tag so the custom font loads.  Is there a way to make the SVG show as one image rather than many elements?  Thank you!

Comment: If you're delivering code to the front end then it's going to be scannable. You can put it in an img tag but anyone who knows their stuff will open that svg in a new tab and then scan it. Maybe what you really want is a png or a jpeg.

Comment: Ok.  There were no issues with security, it was just that it kind of looked bad when you saw those different parts highlighted.  But that is fine if I cannot do anything.

Comment: Sure, I understand. But the average user is not inspecting your website. In fact, you're luck if the average user stays on your website for more than 3 seconds.

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind. Thank you!